# Convert only specific elements of an array to string in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am learning php. I have an array as:

```
Array ( [0] => 160 [1] => 380 [2] => 180)
```

I have to convert this array to a string. I am aware of [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). But it joins all the array elements with a string. But if i have to join just the first 2 elements or specific elements which method should i use.? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using array_slice will enable you join a part of an array:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

```
$array = array(100, 200, 300);
echo implode( '-', array_slice($array,0,2) );
```

Comment: Why is `array_splice` preferable over `array_slice`?